# ios - Name of the app near Back button after opening it through push-notification

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

My iOS application now has only two ViewControllers, the main one with the list of cards and the second one with the information about opened card. On the first ViewController there is no name of my application on the Navigation Bar, while on the second View there is only Back button which returns me to the first screen.

My application has push-notification, which opens the second ViewController with Back Button, but if I open it this way, there is a name of my Application near Back button. When I click on it, it returns me to the first ViewController, but this time there is also the name of Application on the top. I don't want to see app name. How can I solve this problem?

I tested it using both iPhone 4 and iPad.

Comment: When you say on the top, you mean on your navigation bar right?

Comment: @elio.d Yeah, you're right. I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: added one possible answer let me know if it solve your issue

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to set the navigation bar title on the viewWillAppear method of you main view controller

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated]
     [self.navigationController.navigationItem setTitle:@""]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

By défaut, the back button text is the precedent view controller title.

So if your 1st view controller has "YourApp" as title, when you will push a new Controller, the back text will be "YourApp"

You can override it easily :

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Select your **ViewController** -> **Navigation Item** -> **Show the attributes inspector** -> **Back button** "Back"

Hope this help you